# cluster is not forming by extending DiscoveryStrategyFactory

Tags: hazelcast

1.we have requirement to form cluster using custom strategy .
we have extended DiscoveryStrategyFactory and reading ip address from windows host file.

2.it is working currently on local but cluster not forming when same program is run on another server.

[console and hazelcast xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey2U0.png)

Comment: What do your `hosts` files look like?

Comment: 1.can not share host file for security puspose.                                                                                    2.it contains ip address and url of organizations environments hence can not shared.                   3.it contains ip address and host name with it